# Does Microsoft Office 365 Business - Microsoft Store Version supports VSTO COM Add-ins?

Tags: office365, vsto, office-addins

Does Microsoft Office 365 Business - **Microsoft Store Version** supports VSTO COM Add-ins?

Add-in not listed on Disabled Add-ins list either.

I've created Dummy Add-in entry as registry key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Word\Addins\Dummy with it's required values (Description, FriendlyName, LoadBehavior, Manifest).

I've put dummy contents for listed key pair values, with no Add-in being listed under COM Add-ins list (for Word in this case).

Add-in appears on COM Add-ins list under Microsoft Office 365 Business, ***Click-to-Run Version*** (another machine), but not appearing under Store Version.

Microsoft Office 365 Business, Microsoft Store Version was preinstalled on Dell Latitude laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be "No, it doesn't". Under the section "Is Office in the Microsoft Store any different than an existing Office desktop suite?" in the [FAQ](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/faq-office-on-windows-10-in-s-mode-717193b5-ff9f-4388-84c0-277ddf07fe3f) it says:

> Some Office add-ins may not work if Office is installed via the
>   Microsoft Store. We're working to make Office in the Microsoft Store
>   compatible with more add-ins.

There is a [UserVoice](https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/264636-general/suggestions/35176501-office-365-store-version-does-not-recognize-excel) suggestion that requests this functionality.